# Short Stories - Questions

Tags: style, technique, plot, structure

How many Stories would be required for it to be considered as a Collection of Short Stories ideally? 
What would be the approximate Word Count for a Short Story?

Comment: Because stories vary from a single sentence or paragraph up to novellas, and because collections vary in size from chapbooks to really thick volumes, I don't think there's an answer to your question.

Comment: Yeah... it's arbitrary - especially now with so many books being self published digitally so they aren't constrained by traditional word counts.  Are these short stories that have been previously published?  A lot of people have started publishing their short stories separately rather than bundled into a collection.  The Wool series by Hugh Howey started that way.

Answer (score 0):

Short story lengths can vary widely, and you can do nearly anything you want, but certain lengths are more easily accepted and more easily published. [Does this help?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/in-a-short-story-how-long-is-too-long)

As for how many stories it takes to make a collection, I've got no idea, but [some other smart people have given their thoughts here](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6712/how-many-short-stories-make-a-collection).

Hope that helps!